# Class confusion for deserializing JSON object to

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using json2csharp.com and pasted my Json raw data in it to create class for deserializing object to, but it's generated many classes (*RootObject and other* called "**__invalid_type__"**) and it's now confusing me... as I got many "**__invalid_type__**".

My question is now : Do I also need to use **__invalid_type__** class in my C# source code?

Below is the raw-json

```html
{"Id":31,
"Title":"Japan Toyoda",
"SubTitle":"Japenese, WR14 3HE",
"Description":"\u003Cp\u003 is a town of about 300,000 people located in South on the A449 80 miles south west of the city of Naga. properties.\u003C\/p\u003E",
"InvestStrategy":"\u003Cp\u003Hokido Construction Ltd is offering \u00a3597,826 debt investment via the Bond promoted by with Us for the refinance of , expiry of the Bond Term.\u003C\/p\u003E",
"InvestType":"NorthBounds",
"TargetReturn":"50.0000",
"InvestTerm":12,"MinimalPrice":"1.00","SharePrice":1,
"TotalShares":597826,
"AvailableShares":186670,
"BoughtShares":411156,
"InformationMemorandumUrl":"https:\/\/www.google.jp\/properties\/propertyInformationFile\/hokidoRoad",
"MainImage":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/properties_images\/image0001.png",
"Images":["https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/properties_images\/image078901.png","https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/properties_images\/6a5940077eec9cc283.JPG","https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/properties_images\/4f9036fa91ede.jpeg"],
"Plan":["https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/properties_images\/4f9036694fa91ede.jpeg"],
"ListAttributes":{"1":{"name":"Second Charge Security","icon":"checking-square","value":""},"2":{"name":"","icon":"checking-square-o","value":""},"3":{"name":"Second Board","icon":"checking-square-o","value":""},"4":{"name":"Water","icon":"fa-check-square-o","value":""}},
"Latitude":"130.10599000","Longitude":"-78.210610000","Url":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/ref\/bb88f8054731878b209c\/youtoo"}
```

*Below is the generated class from json2csharp.com*

```
public class __invalid_type__1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__3
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__4
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class ListAttributes
{
    public __invalid_type__1 __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__2 __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__3 __invalid_name__3 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__4 __invalid_name__4 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string InvestStrategy { get; set; }
    public string InvestType { get; set; }
    public string TargetReturn { get; set; }
    public int InvestTerm { get; set; }
    public string MinimalInvest { get; set; }
    public int SharePrice { get; set; }
    public int TotalShares { get; set; }
    public int AvailableShares { get; set; }
    public int BoughtShares { get; set; }
    public string InformationMemorandumUrl { get; set; }
    public string MainImage { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
    public List<string> FloorPlan { get; set; }
    public ListAttributes ListAttributes { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct class structure for your JSON structure can be also represented as

```
public class Listattributes
{
    public dataObject _1 { get; set; }
    public dataObject _2 { get; set; }
    public dataObject _3 { get; set; }
    public dataObject _4 { get; set; }
}

public class dataObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

rootObject remains the same

Comment: I'm still getting error in **RootObject** when trying to map json to c# obejct here :  `if 
                {
                    APIdatas2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }

                    Console.WriteLine();

                var stringJson2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(APIdatas2);`  Seems like it's doesn't match with the class. Can you please assist?

Comment: Can you provide the sample document that contains more than one item for "APIdatas2"?

Comment: I added API endpoint in the first post. the error coming from the class object. So The mapping is giving issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to use QuickType (https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs) because it will generate `Dictionary` properties. `Dictionary` is needed because the source JSON has numeric keys such as `"1"` which can't be translated to C# class property names.

I cleaned the JSON to this because the tool kept complaining about backslashes:

```
{"Id":31,
"Title":"....",
"SubTitle":"....",
"Description":"....",
"InvestStrategy":"....",
"InvestType":"....",
"TargetReturn":"50.0000",
"InvestTerm":12,
"MinimalPrice":"1.00",
"SharePrice":1,
"TotalShares":597826,
"AvailableShares":186670,
"BoughtShares":411156,
"InformationMemorandumUrl":"....",
"MainImage":"....",
"Images":["....","....","...."],
"Plan":["...."],
"ListAttributes":{"1":{"name":"....","icon":"....","value":""},"2":{"name":"","icon":"....","value":""},"3":{"name":"....","icon":"....","value":""},"4":{"name":"Water","icon":"....","value":""}},
"Latitude":"130.10599000",
"Longitude":"-78.210610000",
"Url":"...."}
```

Partial output (*):

```
public partial class JsonItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Other props...

    public string[] Images { get; set; }
    public string[] Plan { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ListAttribute> ListAttributes { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public partial class ListAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

(*) : Generated using the option [Just Types]. You can get more complete code using one of the other output options.

Comment: Thanks but what about the remaining **RootObject** class ?

Comment: `RootObject` has been replaced with `JsonItem`. See the output options from the site to get more complete code that uses the class. And of course you are free to give the class any other name that more closely resembles the domain of your application .

Comment: I'm getting exceptiion saying   `$exception {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List1
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.  ewtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`

Comment: Can you please help? It says need to change JSON to JSON array !! How Do I do it please? **Tested with the second endpoint API Id = 31**